# Style Border Textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

First what I want to do:
I have a `Popup` (shown wenn ALT-key is down and hidden when up), indise this a `Border` and inside this a `TextBlock`. This will show the Keybinding for specific fields.

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=txb_ticket_Text}" IsOpen="{Binding ShowTooltip}"
       Style="{DynamicResource TooltipPopup}" >
    <Border Style="{DynamicResource WhiteBorder}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=kb_ticketselection, Path=Key, Converter={StaticResource KeyToString}}"
                   Style="{DynamicResource Tooltip}"/>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

And following threee styles:

```
<Style x:Key="Tooltip" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="WhiteBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="TooltipPopup" TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="-10" />
</Style>
```

Is it possible to make a Style or Template for that? I have, of course, to use it multiple times and it would the easiest to just have to set the Textbinding. None of these three elements has a Template.

My next idea would to create a UserControl with these elements and set a binding to the textproperty of the Textblock?!

---

€dit: meanwhile I created a UserControl, but now i have a simple problem:

I get the following error, but it still works...

> "TargetType 'StandInPopup'" entspricht nicht dem Typ des Elements "Popup".
>
> "TargetType 'StandInPopup'" does not match type of element "popup".

How can i remove the error? OR what causes this error and why does it still work (as expected)?

The UC for reference

```
<UserControl x:Class="PopupTooltip"
             x:Name="ucpopup"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myClass"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ucpopup, Path=TargetElement}" IsOpen="{Binding ShowTooltip}"
               Style="{DynamicResource TooltipPopup}" >
            <Border Style="{DynamicResource WhiteBorder}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ucpopup, Path=MyText}"
                           Style="{DynamicResource Tooltip}"/>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

€€: Here's the rest of the code from the UC, just two Properties I need:

```
Public Class PopupTooltip

    Public Sub New()

        ' Dieser Aufruf ist für den Designer erforderlich.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Fügen Sie Initialisierungen nach dem InitializeComponent()-Aufruf hinzu.

    End Sub

    Private _myText As String
    Public Property MyText() As String
        Get
            Return _myText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _myText = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly MyTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", GetType(String), GetType(PopupTooltip), New PropertyMetadata(""))

    Private _targetElement As UIElement
    Public Property TargetElement() As UIElement
        Get
            Return _targetElement
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As UIElement)
            _targetElement = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly TargetElementProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TargetElement", GetType(UIElement), GetType(PopupTooltip))
End Class
```

Comment: IMHO UserControl is the best approach

Comment: @ganchito55: yeah, I did that meanwhile. But now i get an error that doesn't prevent the whole thing from working. But its still an error...
It's edited in question

Comment: What's `StandInPopup` and where do you use it? It's not in the code you've shown.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know it. Also a search over the full Solution doesn't return a result. This is the way i use the UC: `<FDCom:PopupTooltip MyText="{Binding ElementName=kb_givenname, Path=Key, Converter={StaticResource KeyToString}}" TargetElement="{Binding ElementName=txb_givenname_Text}" />`, since i placed the first like this the error occured. The Designer shows also an error: `Eine Instanz von "PopupTooltip" kann nicht erstellt werden.` I'll just add the rest of the UC above...

Comment: I think StandInPopup is something associated with the Visual Studio Designer. I suspect it's failing to try do the "popup" display in the designer when you have it selected in the xaml. Have you tried restarting visual studio/the machine (to extremes you could also try a repair of the Visual Studio installation). Or at least try it on another computer with visual studio if you have access to one.

Comment: Restart and more didn't helped. If the error occours on another PC i will see next week. But after some googling I found a Solution. I just added the following Code before `InitializeComponent`: `If (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(Me)) Then
            Return
        End If`